Poor layer adhesion on second layer. Why?
First Layer looks perfect second layer I am getting horrible adhesion. It starts out okay as you can see in the bottom left corner and then gets worse.
The bed was manually leveled and auto leveled prior to the print. I am printing with a 1 mm nozzle, 0.7 mm layer height, bed temp is 60 °C, nozzle is 230 °C. The printer is a Creatbot D600 Pro 2.
I am somewhat a novice when it comes to 3D printing so any advice would be appreciated.


How many slow layers do you have, and at what speeds and temperatures are you printing? This is quite a lot of filament you are putting through the nozzle. I guess you could be printing too fast. Please update the question by [edit]. Thanks and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!

What material is this?
